How can I read files from a directory?
So I tried EPS2_GET_DIRECTORY_LISTING and EPS_GET_DIRECTORY_LISTING.
But the issue is, that inside the function, there is a check to verify whether the user has the necessary permssions for transports. The check performed is Function 'TR_AUTHORITY_CHECK_DISPLAY'.
I have no idea what it has to do with file permissions...
I started digging. Turns out in note https://me.sap.com/notes/0003221036 it's written, that the Function should not be used anymore since it lost support. But they don't specify a replacement.
Have you any suggestions what I might use here?
I call the function with a path and file_mask, so the replacement needs to have such possibility also.
Either that, or someone can explain me that I need the Transport rights to use the function.

I checked my programs, and I use those same functions as you do. Then I've did a fast seek in the SAP forum and found an idea that maybe will work for you: take a look at program RSWATCH0  (AL11) and its forms to fill file lists. There are a bunch of FMs that maybe you'll be able to make them work.

Thanks for the confimation that you also use it for reading.

Side note: the KBA 3221036 doesn't say that EPS2_GET_DIRECTORY_LISTING has lost support, it says it's not released to be used by customers, like the vast majority of existing objects. It has never been released for customer use. I'd say that only 0.001% of all objects are released to be used by customers. I don't know why SAP is publishing one KBA per non-released object at a time instead of providing an easy way to identify the objects released for customer use...

Of course, the easiest solution is to duplicate the function module and adapt the code as you wish.
Otherwise, if you don't want to depend on unofficial solutions, the only way I know to work with the server file system is to use the transaction code SM49 and the function module SXPG_COMMAND_EXECUTE, which are meant to run direct commands on the server.
For instance, you may create a "server command" in SM49 (e.g. ZGET_DIRECTORY) and configure it with ls for UNIX-like systems, cmd /c dir for Windows, etc.
You may invoke the command ZGET_DIRECTORY by calling SXPG_COMMAND_EXECUTE and convert the result in something close to EPS2_GET_DIRECTORY_LISTING in order to reduce the number of adaptations of your custom programs using EPS2_GET_DIRECTORY_LISTING.
Example for SM49 and ABAP code:

DATA exec_protocol TYPE TABLE OF btcxpm.
DATA status        TYPE extcmdexex-status.
DATA exitcode      TYPE extcmdexex-exitcode.

DATA(directory) = CONV sxpgcolist-parameters( '/tmp' ).
DATA(host) = CONV rfcdisplay-rfchost( sy-host ).

CALL FUNCTION 'SXPG_COMMAND_EXECUTE'
  EXPORTING  commandname                   = 'ZGET_DIRECTORY'
             additional_parameters         = directory
             operatingsystem               = sy-opsys
             targetsystem                  = host
  IMPORTING  status                        = status
             exitcode                      = exitcode
  TABLES     exec_protocol                 = exec_protocol
  EXCEPTIONS no_permission                 = 1
             command_not_found             = 2
             parameters_too_long           = 3
             security_risk                 = 4
             wrong_check_call_interface    = 5
             program_start_error           = 6
             program_termination_error     = 7
             x_error                       = 8
             parameter_expected            = 9
             too_many_parameters           = 10
             illegal_command               = 11
             wrong_asynchronous_parameters = 12
             cant_enq_tbtco_entry          = 13
             jobcount_generation_error     = 14
             OTHERS                        = 15.

IF sy-subrc <> 0 OR status = 'E'.
  " handle the error
ELSE.
  CASE sy-opsys.
    WHEN 'UNIX' OR 'Linux'.
      " Convert the output of "ls -la" into EPS2FILI format
      " https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html
      TYPES output_eps2_get_directory_list TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF eps2fili WITH EMPTY KEY.

      " -rw-rw----  1 l4xadm   sapsys    317674 2024-11-04 15:24:30.297148558 +0000 ABAON-BA
      " https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103114/what-do-the-fields-in-ls-al-output-mean
      TYPES:
        BEGIN OF ls_output_fields,
          file_type_mode      TYPE c LENGTH 10, " type of entry - (file), d (directory), s (system), etc. + rwxrwxrwx
          count_hard_links    TYPE c LENGTH 4,
          owner_name          TYPE c LENGTH 8,
          owner_group         TYPE c LENGTH 8,
          size_bytes          TYPE string,
          last_modif_date_iso TYPE string,
          file_name           TYPE c LENGTH 200, " possibly truncated
        END OF ls_output_fields.
      TYPES formatted_ls_output TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ls_output_fields WITH EMPTY KEY.

      " Delete the "total" line
      DELETE exec_protocol INDEX 1.

      DATA(output_eps2_get_directory_list) = VALUE output_eps2_get_directory_list( ).
      LOOP AT exec_protocol REFERENCE INTO DATA(exec_output_line).
        DATA(ls_output_fields) = VALUE ls_output_fields( ).
        FIND REGEX '^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+)\s+(.*)$' ##REGEX_POSIX
             IN exec_output_line->message
             SUBMATCHES
                  ls_output_fields-file_type_mode
                  ls_output_fields-count_hard_links
                  ls_output_fields-owner_name
                  ls_output_fields-owner_group
                  ls_output_fields-size_bytes
                  ls_output_fields-last_modif_date_iso
                  ls_output_fields-file_name.
        IF '-' = substring( val = ls_output_fields-file_type_mode
                            len = 1 ).
          INSERT VALUE eps2fili( name  = ls_output_fields-file_name
                                 size  = ls_output_fields-size_bytes
                                 mtim  = CONV #( ls_output_fields-last_modif_date_iso )
                                 owner = ls_output_fields-owner_name )
                 INTO TABLE output_eps2_get_directory_list.
        ENDIF.
      ENDLOOP.
  ENDCASE.
  SORT output_eps2_get_directory_list BY name.
ENDIF.

NB: SM69 is an alias of SM49.
